# Null reference exeption when I try to call an instanced object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question probably comes from a bad understanding of inheritance and composition. I have a couple of classes with inheritance BasePlayerClass=>SpaceShipClass=>SpaceShipObject. I dont understand how to call the instantiated class Player from another classes, so that it saves its properties and doesn't get the null value.

```
public class CreatePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Sprite SCALPEL, WARPER, ORION;
    public SpriteRenderer SelectedCharacterSprite;
    public Skill_Slot newSkillslot;

    private readonly string SelectedCharacter = null;





public void Start()
{
  PlayerCreation();

  newSkillslot.CreateSkillSlots();

}

public void PlayerCreation()
{
BasePlayerClass player = new BasePlayerClass();
SelectedCharacterSprite = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    int getCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(SelectedCharacter);

        switch(getCharacter){

            case 0:
            SelectedCharacterSprite.sprite = SCALPEL;
            player.SpaceshipClass = new ScalpelSpaceship();
            break;
            case 1:
            SelectedCharacterSprite.sprite = WARPER;
            player.SpaceshipClass = new WarperSpaceship();
            break;
            case 2:
            SelectedCharacterSprite.sprite = ORION;
            player.SpaceshipClass = new OrionSpaceship();
            break;

        }
}
}





public class Skill_Slot : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Skill SignedSkill;
   private Image qImg;
   private Image wImg;
   private Image eImg;



    public GameObject qSkillSlot;  
    public GameObject wSkillSlot;
    public GameObject eSkillSlot;

    public BasePlayerClass player;







   public void CreateSkillSlots()
   {
      Debug.Log(player.SpaceshipClass);
      qImg = qSkillSlot.GetComponent<Image>();
      wImg = wSkillSlot.GetComponent<Image>();
      SignedSkill = player.SpaceshipClass.QSkill;

      switch(player.SpaceshipClass.QSkill.SkillIndex){
        case 1:
        qImg.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("BasicAttack");
        SignedSkill = player.SpaceshipClass.QSkill;
        break;
        case 2:
        qImg.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("OrionMove");
        break;
        case 3:

        break;

   }
   switch(player.SpaceshipClass.WSkill.SkillIndex){
        case 1:
        wImg.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("BasicAttack");
        break;
        case 2:
        wImg.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("OrionMove");
        SignedSkill = player.SpaceshipClass.WSkill;
        break;
        case 3:

        break;

   }
}
}
```

Comment: `public TestClass newTest = new TestClass();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what is your desired action, but what do you want by calling `PlayerCreation()`?

It seems like, if there are no side-effect in your constructor of `BasePlayerClass` and `SpaceShipObject`, function `PlayerCreation()` does literally *nothing*. You just declared local variable `Player`, and do something with it, and the scope ends. After the function call, GC will collect that `Player` local variable, since there is no viable way to access it. Nothing to do with *Inheritance* until here.

Which means, `Player` of `TestClass` and the local variable `Player` in `PlayerCreation()` is *entirely, totally, definitely* different thing. Again, I'm not sure what is your desired behavior, but since it seems you are new to C#, take a look at below code snip:

```cs
public class CreatePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestClass newTest;

    public void Start(){
        newTest = new TestClass();  // Come on, You have to create an instance to use class!

        newTest.Player = PlayerCreation(); // And now newTest will call the function
        newTest.CallPlayerClass();         // with the return value of PlayerCreation().
    }

    public BasePlayerClass PlayerCreation(){
        BasePlayerClass player = new BasePlayerClass();  // BTW, for local variables, 
                                                         // using camelCase is recommended.
        Player.SpaceshipClass = new SpaceShipObject();
        return player;  // You have to return the local variable to use it!
    }
}
```

In the above example, you made a new instance of `TestClass` class, and assigned it's field `Player` with the return value of `PlayerCreation()` value.

I strongly suggest you to analyze this code on your own, and take a look of OOP programming. Even until here, your problem had nothing to do with *Inheritance*.

Comment: I edited my post, to be more specific. I need to make the player variable global, so that I can use it in other classes and methods. And its properties should be defined in PlayerCreation().

Comment: Then you can define `static` variable, like `public static BasePlayerClass Player`, and assign it's value in `PlayerCreation()` function.